# Does BEM really "ban" all reset/default rules?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm trying to get along with BEM methodology in my CSS (actually SCSS) files, but I can't get one thing. What is wrong with simple reset/default rules. I read documentation and understand, that it can be a problem when re-using same CSS components in another project, but I think it's better than typing 100+ times "box-sizing: border-box;" or "font-family: var(--main-font);". When re-using code you can always check reset rules in the previous one, most probably they will be the same.

Is it really a bad practice against BEM philosophy or some exceptions are allowed?

Comment: Github’s standards here https://gist.github.com/stowball/6ca2fc1d868ebb049f043dbec782dd68. BEM is a methodology so alter it to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

BEM is just sane recomendations. Exceptions are always allowed.

But actually you don't really need `box-sizing: border-box` for **each** of your blocks. Try to count blocks with both `width` and `padding` set. And if there's just a few isn't it a reason to drop reset? ;)

Comment: Actually around 75% of my project did contain width and padding so I will stick to "_defaults.scss" file, thanks for your answer.